# Nginx catching wildcard subdomain rather than exact

Tags: nginx

I'm having some issues with my nginx setup.

Im trying to set up a subdomain for another system path, but for some reason, nginx redirects to a catch-all wildcart rather than the exact.

Config looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        root /www/example.com/public;

        index index.php index.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        root /www/example.com/public_static;

        index index.html

        server_name static.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        root /www/example.com/public;

        server_name *.examlpe.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /nosub.html;
        }
}
```

There's a reverse-proxy running as well, that config looks like this:

```
upstream internalservers {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_pass http://internalservers;
        }
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        root /www/default/

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /nodomain.html;
        }
}
```

When i try to access the specific subdomain, static, it redirects to the catch-all subdomain defined, hence I dont think it's an issue in the proxy setup.

Comment: I see no obvious problem. Run `nginx -T` and post the output.

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: OK? Now restart nginx with this configuration.

Comment: I have, and it does not work. It forwards to the catchall when trying to access the exact subdomain.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you are using this configuration? How do you know? You didn't post the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: Im not sure what other output you want me to post. I posted the exact output...
https://i.imgur.com/Cdmt0Gv.png

Comment: That is the output of `nginx -t`, not `nginx -T`.

Comment: If i try to add the static.example.com to the first setup, like this: `server_name example.com www.example.com static.example.com` it will resolve, just like www, but for some reason, not in its own server block.

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `index` directive.

Comment: Oh, im sorry, i was not aware there was a difference.
https://pastebin.com/0cyaeQtB - ive anonymised the domains

Comment: @RichardSmith good spot. That was it.